# How can l post on facebook from android app with API wall without checking?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, android-facebook

How can l post on facebook from android app with API wall without checking (displaying "post to wall" screen from facebook)

Answer (score 4):

Just call `publishStory(StringYouNeed,StringYouNeed,StringYouNeed);`
And implement this in your activity / Fragment :

```
private void publishStory(String hash, String title, String user) {

    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    if (session != null){
        // Check for publish permissions    
        List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
        if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
            pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
            Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
                    .NewPermissionsRequest(getActivity(), PERMISSIONS);
            session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
            return;
        }
        Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
        postParams.putString("name", title);
        postParams.putString("caption", "bla bla");
        postParams.putString("description", "bla bla");
        postParams.putString("link", "http://blabla.com/"+hash);

        Request.Callback callback= new Request.Callback() {
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                JSONObject graphResponse = response
                        .getGraphObject()
                        .getInnerJSONObject();
                String postId = null;
                try {
                    postId = graphResponse.getString("id");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.i(TAG,
                            "JSON error "+ e.getMessage());
                }
                FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                if (error != null) {
                    debug.print("erreur");
                } 
            }
        };

        Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed", postParams, 
                HttpMethod.POST, callback);

        RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
        task.execute();
    }

}
private boolean isSubsetOf(Collection<String> subset, Collection<String> superset) {
    for (String string : subset) {
        if (!superset.contains(string)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Works perfect for me, hope this help.

Comment: How tag friends to this post in facebook?

Comment: What is PERMISSIONS ??

Comment: @Pranav Mahajan: see here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17483757/get-publish-action-permission-after-getting-read-permissions-from-facebook

Comment: I get: Session: an attempt was made to request new permissions for a session that is not currently open.

Answer (score 1):

the bellow tutorial help you to do this

http://www.integratingstuff.com/2010/10/14/integrating-facebook-into-an-android-application/

Comment: This blog post is from 2010, and uses an old (and deprecated) version of the Facebook SDK. I would use the official Facebook developer site instead - https://developers.facebook.com/android

Answer (score 0):

Create your web page and give a link

```
// use this function
private void shareToFacebook() {

    // add urlToShare to your own site url
    String urlToShare = "http://mithsoft.net/home/";
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, urlToShare);

   // See if official Facebook app is found
    boolean facebookAppFound = false;
    List<ResolveInfo> matches = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo info : matches) {
        if (info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().startsWith("com.facebook.katana")) {
            intent.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
            facebookAppFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }
   // As fallback, launch sharer.php in a browser
    if (!facebookAppFound) {
        String sharerUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" + urlToShare;
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(sharerUrl));
    }
    startActivity(intent);
}
```