# Get publish_action permission after getting read permissions from Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-authentication

I'm integrating `Facebook` log in in my application. I'm able to get the read permissions but how to get publish permissions from Facebook SDK.

This is how I'm asking for the permissions for read:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
Session currentSession = Session.getActiveSession();
if (currentSession == null
    || currentSession.getState().isClosed()) {
    Session session = new Session.Builder(context).build();
    Session.setActiveSession(session);
    currentSession = session;
}

if (currentSession.isOpened()) {
    // Do whatever u want. User has logged in

} else if (!currentSession.isOpened()) {
    // Ask for username and password
    OpenRequest op = new Session.OpenRequest((Activity) context);

    op.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SSO_WITH_FALLBACK);
    op.setCallback(null);

    List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
    permissions.add("user_likes");
    permissions.add("email");
    permissions.add("user_birthday");
    permissions.add("user_location");
    permissions.add("user_interests");
    permissions.add("friends_birthday");
    op.setPermissions(permissions);

    Session session = new Builder(MainActivity.this).build();
    Session.setActiveSession(session);
    session.openForRead(op);
    }
}
});
```

If user granted the permission I'm able to get `access_token` and doing my things on `onActivityResult`. Here is what I'm doing with that:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if (Session.getActiveSession() != null)
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode,
            resultCode, data);

Session currentSession = Session.getActiveSession();
if (currentSession == null || currentSession.getState().isClosed()) {
    Session session = new Session.Builder(context).build();
    Session.setActiveSession(session);
    currentSession = session;
}

if (currentSession.isOpened()) {
    Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

    @Override
    public void call(final Session session, SessionState state,
        Exception exception) {

        if (session.isOpened()) {

        Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
            new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                    Response response) {
                if (user != null) {

                    TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
                    TextView access_token_txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.access_token);
                    TextView email_txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);                                           

                    access_token = session.getAccessToken();
                    firstName = user.getFirstName();
                    fb_user_id = user.getId();                                          

                    access_token_txt.setText(access_token);

                    JSONObject graphResponse = response
                        .getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();

                    fbEmail = null;
                    try {
                        fbEmail = graphResponse.getString("email");

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    email_txt.setText(fbEmail);                                         
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
}
}
```

I have read `Facebook Developer` doc as explained here [Permissions - Facebook Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#optimizing), that I cant ask publish permissions with read permissions.

First user will have to ask for read and when user autorizes that then we can ask for publish permissions.

How can I get publish permissions from Facebook log in after user as granted read permissions.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: i am stuck on login facebook. I can login when native app available but not able to login and authorize app if native app is not available.  here is my question can you provide answer on this.  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21336314/facebook-after-login-not-coming-back-but-asking-login-again]

Comment: I have commented on your question try it and reply if it works.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have got the answer to my question. Just have to open session after getting read permissions and then ask for publish permissions. Here is what I have done:

```
private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
private boolean pendingPublishReauthorization = false;
```

Add this in your `onActivityResult`:

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    if (session != null) {

        // Check for publish permissions
        List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
        if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
            pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
            Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(
                    this, PERMISSIONS);
            session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
            return;
        }
    }
```

Also get this method integrated in the code:

```
private boolean isSubsetOf(Collection<String> subset,
        Collection<String> superset) {
    for (String string : subset) {
        if (!superset.contains(string)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

By doing these things, I"m able to get read as well publish permissions simultaneously.

Hope this will help others.

Comment: But it opens the login box once again, that is simple not acceptable from a user point of view. Can i do it with user re-entering the username and password.

Comment: @jeevs I think showing the pop up once again is better than reentering the username and password for Facebook login. I'm working on it to have a proper flow like not showing the pop up on onActivityResult().

Comment: That pop up is login Pop up of facebook SDK, while in background the post is published, so its of no use. Why we will need that login pop-up when the post is already been published.

Comment: @jeevs I could get your question properly, can you make a seperate thread and ask your doubt there and post a link here, so that I can see what are you asking?

Comment: Small suggestion: !permissions.containsAll(PERMISSIONS)

Comment: Also from May 2014 you should request publish permission on app settings page, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/

Comment: I get: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Session: an attempt was made to request new permissions for a session that is not currently open.

Comment: It would be much more valuable if you posted the whole code for this.

Comment: i am trying  above code app crash and logcat showing  exception   ava.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=64206, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.picatabtogosample.activities/com.picatabtogosample.activities.FBActivity1}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Session: an attempt was made to request new permissions for a session that has a pending request.

Answer (score 3):

From the facebook sdk 3.0 documents you can not give the read and publish permission simultaniously. But once you open the session with read permission later you can update this session to publish permission, by UiLifecycleHelper class. Once the session state changes to SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED means session updated with publish permission. Here is sample code for you hope this help you.

```
public class Example {
    private static final int REAUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE = 100;
    private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions", "publish_stream");
    private static final String PENDING_PUBLISH_KEY = "pendingPublishReauthorization";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_submit_post);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    publishStory();
}

private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {

    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (exception != null) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(SubmitPost.this)
                    .setMessage(exception.getMessage())
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();
        } else {
            SubmitPost.this.onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    }
};

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

 if (state.isOpened()) {
            if (pendingAnnounce && state.equals(SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED)) {
                // Session updated with new permissions so try publishing once more.
                pendingAnnounce = false;
                //call your method here to publish something on facebook 
                publishStory();
            }
        }
    }

private void requestPublishPermissions(Session session) {
    if (session != null) {
        pendingAnnounce = true;
        Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);

        newPermissionsRequest.setRequestCode(REAUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE);
        Session mSession = Session.openActiveSessionFromCache(this);
        mSession.addCallback(callback);
        mSession.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
    }
}

private void publishStory() {

    // Check for publish permissions
    List<String> permissions = this.session.getPermissions();
    if (!permissions.containsAll(Arrays.asList(PERMISSIONS ))) {
        this.requestPublishPermissions(this.session);
        this.is_return = true;
        return;
    }

    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null) {
        CreateFBPost();
    }

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case REAUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE:
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null) {
            session.onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me how can I update my code for getting that permission? That will be very helpful.

Comment: // Check for publish permissions
    List<String> permissions = this.session.getPermissions();
    if (!permissions.containsAll(Arrays.asList(PERMISSIONS ))) {
        this.requestPublishPermissions(this.session);
        this.is_return = true;
        return;
    } this peace of code will check whether you got permissions if yes publishStory will be called else requestPublishPermissions method will add the permission with your session