# Facebook after login not coming back but asking login again

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

I am trying to implement Facebook login functionality in my app and getting token after giving publish permission.

For this I follow following steps.

1. Create app on Facebook(Fill all details like app name, Hash key(Release), Class name, Package Name, Single Sign On)
2. App is available for all user now.
3. Then i am using app id in my manifest.xml

Everything is working fine with me if Native Facebook app is install on my mobile. But if native app is not install then it will open facebook webview after filling login info it ask me to authorize after clicking on ok button it again asking me to login. And this process will continue.

****After login and allowing app permission it's not coming back to my screen but it asking login me again****.

Here is my screen shot.

[image]

Here is second screen shot

[image]

After clicking on ok then it's asking me again to login.  It's loop login - authorize- login..
Here is my full code:

I am using my own button so i am not adding xml code.

```
  public class FBActivity extends Activity {
Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new SessionStatusCallback();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.registartionwithmultiple);
    printHashKey();
    bundle = savedInstanceState;
    permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
    readpermissions = new ArrayList<String>();

    permissions.add("publish_actions");
    readpermissions.add("email");
    executeFacebookLogin();     
}       

private void executeFacebookLogin() {
     Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);         
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if(session == null) {
        if(bundle != null) {
            Log.i("TEST","RESTORING FROM BUNDLE");
            session = Session.restoreSession(this, null, statusCallback, bundle);
        }
        if(session == null) {
            Log.i("TEST","CREATE NEW SESSION");
            session = new Session(this);
        }
        Session.setActiveSession(session);          
        session.addCallback(statusCallback);
        if(session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {

            session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback).setPermissions(readpermissions));

        } 
    }

    if(session.isClosed()) {
        session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
        Session.setActiveSession(null);
    }
    if(!session.isOpened()) {

        session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback).setPermissions(readpermissions));
        Log.i("FB Login ","Open for Publish");
    } else {
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, statusCallback);
    }

}


private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {

    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        //Check if Session is Opened or not
        processSessionStatus(session, state, exception);
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void processSessionStatus(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    Log.i("TEST","Session in process session "+session);
    if(session != null && session.isOpened()) {

        if(session.getPermissions().contains("publish_actions")) {
            //Show Progress Dialog 
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            dialog.setMessage("Loggin in..");
            dialog.show();
            Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {


                    if (dialog!=null && dialog.isShowing()) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                    if(user != null) {
                        Map<String, Object> responseMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                        GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();
                        responseMap = graphObject.asMap();
                        Log.i("FbLogin", "Response Map KeySet - " + responseMap.keySet());
                        // TODO : Get Email responseMap.get("email"); 

                        fb_id = user.getId();
                        fb_email = null;
                        user.getBirthday();
                        fb_userName = user.getUsername();
                        fb_fullname = user.getFirstName() +" "+user.getLastName();

                        String name = (String) responseMap.get("name");
                        if (responseMap.get("email")!=null) {
                            fb_email = responseMap.get("email").toString();
                            Log.i("TEST", "FB_ID="+fb_id +"email="+fb_email+"name="+name+"user_name="+user.getUsername()+"birthday="+user.getBirthday());
                            Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
                            tokenKey = session.getAccessToken();
                            SharedPreferenceStoring myPrefsClass = new SharedPreferenceStoring();
                            myPrefsClass.storingFBToken(FBActivity.this, tokenKey);

                            finish();

                        }
                        else {
                            //Clear all session info & ask user to login again
                            Session session = Session.getActiveSession();                               
                            if(session != null) {
                                session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {

            session.requestNewPublishPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(FBActivity.this, permissions));

        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.i("TEST","Activity result");
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d("FbLogin", "Result Code is - " + resultCode +"");
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(FBActivity.this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // TODO Save current session
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    Session.saveSession(session, outState);
}
```

}

I also getting hash key..   Here is code for hash key

```
private void printHashKey() {
    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "com.myapp",
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KeyHash:",
                    Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }
}
```

I also add `Internet Permission` in `AndroidManifest.xml` and `meta-data` for Facebook  .

Hope all this information is sufficient if need any thing more will surely update my question.

Please give me any reference or hint.

Comment: First remove old fb SDK.Download the latest fb SDK and reference it to your project.May be this will solve ur problem.

Comment: I tried but not working with me.. :-(

Comment: @SandipArmalPatil Indiandroid is right. You'll have to pass keyhash value to facebook console. Make sure you're passing two keyhashes value. Both will be different.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto two hashes key?

Comment: @Anupam: it's already same value in facebook.java file under android package

Comment: Oh ya sorry! Let me give you a better solution after checking your code.

Comment: @Anupam: thank you... will wait for your solution.. because i am stuck on this from last 4-5 days. :-(

Answer (score 1):

u need a library [easyfacebookandroidsdk.jar](http://www.general-files.pw/download/gs1a25bee7h32i0/easyfacebookandroidsdk_2.0.jar.html) and build it up in ur project

use this code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LoginListener{

EditText et1;
 private FBLoginManager fbLoginManager;
Button b;

//replace it with your own Facebook App ID
public final String FacebookTesting="218874471621782";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
connectToFacebook();

}


public void connectToFacebook(){

  //read about Facebook Permissions here:
  //http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/
  String permissions[] = {
//          "user_about_me",  
//          "user_activities",
//          "user_birthday",
//          "user_checkins",
//          "user_education_history",   
//          "user_events",
//          "user_groups",
//          "user_hometown",
//          "user_interests",
//          "user_likes",
//          "user_location",
//          "user_notes",
//            "user_online_presence",
//          "user_photo_video_tags",
//          "user_photos",
//          "user_relationships",
//          "user_relationship_details",
//         "user_religion_politics",
//         "user_status", 
//         "user_videos",
//          "user_website",
//          "user_work_history",
//          "email",
//
//          "read_friendlists",
//          "read_insights",
//          "read_mailbox",
//          "read_requests",
//          "read_stream",
//          "xmpp_login",
//          "ads_management",
//          "create_event",
//          "manage_friendlists",
//          "manage_notifications",
//          "offline_access",
//          "publish_checkins",
    "publish_stream",
//          "rsvp_event",
//          "sms",
    //"publish_actions",

//          "manage_pages"

  };

  fbLoginManager = new FBLoginManager(this,
    R.layout.activity_main, 
    FacebookTesting, 
    permissions);

  if(fbLoginManager.existsSavedFacebook()){
   fbLoginManager.loadFacebook();
  }
  else{
   fbLoginManager.login();
  }
 }





@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return true;
}


 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, android.content.Intent data){


 fbLoginManager.loginSuccess(data);
 }

public void loginSuccess(Facebook facebook) {
//  GraphApi graphApi = new GraphApi(facebook);
 new getDataBackgroundThread().execute(facebook);
//    User user = new User();

//    try{
//     user = graphApi.getMyAccountInfo();
//
//     //update your status if logged in
//     graphApi.setStatus("Hello, world!");
//    } catch(EasyFacebookError e){
//     Log.d("TAG: ", e.toString());
//    }

//    fbLoginManager.displayToast("Hey, " + user.getFirst_name() + "! Login success!");
}

@Override
public void logoutSuccess() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@Override
public void loginFail() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



 class getDataBackgroundThread extends AsyncTask<Facebook, Void, String> {

    private Exception exception;


    protected String doInBackground(Facebook... urls) {
        try{
             GraphApi graphApi = new GraphApi(urls[0]);

              User user = new User();

              try{
            //   user = graphApi.getMyAccountInfo();

               //update your status if logged in
               //graphApi.setStatus("My android App "+"VivekAppTest");
                  graphApi.setStatus("Hello "+"VivekAppTest");
              } catch(EasyFacebookError e){
               Log.d("TAG: ", e.toString());
              }
        return "posted";
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            return null;
        }


}
    protected void onPostExecute(String ipr) {
        // TODO: check this.exception 
        // TODO: do something with the feed
//
//               Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
//               startActivity(i); 
//               finish();
//              Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Post Successful !", 1);
//              toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL,0, 130);
//              toast.show();
//          
    }
 }
}
```

Get your Facebook App id & replace it in the code. I always use this code whenever i have to post the text on FB.

In manifest give Internet permission
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

Thats all

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

So what I wanted to tell you is, you'll have to find the key hashes values and put it in facebook console, Use below code for getting Key Hash Values:

```
try {
               PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.key", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
               for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                    md.update(signature.toByteArray());

                      TextView tvmyName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.KeyText);
                      tvmyName.setText(Base64.encodeBytes(md.digest()));
                      Log.d("KEY_HASH", Base64.encodeBytes(md.digest()));


               }
            } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

            }
```

**KeyHash Value 1: tvmyName.setText(Base64.encodeBytes(md.digest()));**

**KeyHash Value 2: Log.d("KEY_HASH", Base64.encodeBytes(md.digest()));**

See the below image for passing keyhash values in your facebook console :
[image]

Comment: But i am already doing this... i already get hash key and put it in app console of Facebook.   But still it's not working

Comment: Did you pass two key hashes value as I passed, because in one of my app, I was having same issue in one of my apps, with 10 inch tablets only. and I was passing only one what came from log. thereafter I passed both, and then it worked. :)

Comment: @SandipArmalPatil Are you sure you passed two key hashes? One for debug and the other for release?

Comment: yes.. absolutely i am passing two hashes key one for release and one for debug.  No any log cat error

Answer (score 0):

First of all, avoid copying `Facebook SDK` into your current workspace, keep it somewhere and just add the working set of `Facebook SDK` into your workspace.

I have tried just a simple app and getting some permissions from the user. Here is the code which I have tried it was working just perfectly fine with me without Facebook app installed on the device.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements StatusCallback {

final Context context = this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Session currentSession = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (currentSession == null || currentSession.getState().isClosed()) {
        Session session = new Session.Builder(context).build();
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        currentSession = session;
    }

    if (currentSession.isOpened()) {
        // Do whatever u want. User has logged in

    } else if (!currentSession.isOpened()) {
        // Ask for username and password
        OpenRequest op = new Session.OpenRequest((Activity) context);

        op.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SSO_WITH_FALLBACK);
        op.setCallback(null);

        List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
        permissions.add("user_likes");
        permissions.add("email");
        permissions.add("user_birthday");
        permissions.add("user_location");
        permissions.add("user_interests");
        permissions.add("friends_birthday");
        op.setPermissions(permissions);

        Session session = new Builder(MainActivity.this).build();
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        session.openForRead(op);
    }
}

public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    System.out.println("Here");

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (Session.getActiveSession() != null)
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode,
                resultCode, data);

    Session currentSession = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (currentSession == null || currentSession.getState().isClosed()) {
        Session session = new Session.Builder(context).build();
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        currentSession = session;
    }

    if (currentSession.isOpened()) {
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void call(final Session session, SessionState state,
                    Exception exception) {

                if (session.isOpened()) {

                    Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
                            new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                                        Response response) {
                                    if (user != null) {

                                        System.out.println(user.getName());
                                        System.out.println(session
                                                .getAccessToken());
                                        System.out.println(user
                                                .getFirstName());

                                    }
                                }
                            });
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

}
```

On `onActivityResult` I have tried to print some basic info. Just try the code and comment if you bump with any issues with this current code.

Comment: And, yes reconfirm your `keyhash` with your default `debug.keystore` and replace it in the console and also add the class name and current package name on Facebook app dashboard. And try the code above.

Comment: it's showing error on builder Session session = new Builder(FBActivity.this).build(); is this problem related to sdk?

Comment: Remove all your imports use these imports and try.

`import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.Session.Builder;
import com.facebook.Session.OpenRequest;
import com.facebook.Session.StatusCallback;
import com.facebook.SessionLoginBehavior;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;`

Comment: @SandipArmalPatil You are not getting access token. So what about user name and first name?

Comment: @SandipArmalPatil Are you seeing some warnings in logcat? Or can you show me your updated code for this.

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything wrong with your SDK/Process/Code?

Just try this code & Let me know whether It's working fine or having same issue as you mentioned.

[Click here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21497466/when-i-want-to-login-facebook-why-access-token-is-always-null/21500011#21500011)