# Facebook Android Sharing a Link Example Missing PERMISSIONS List

Tags: android, facebook, android-fragments, facebook-permissions, facebook-share

I am following the [Sharing a link using API calls](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share#linkapi) example on the [Facebook Developers](https://developers.facebook.com) site. I am attempting to incorporate the sample `publishStory()` method into my `Fragment`. However I am missing the boolean `pendingPublishReauthorization` and a list `PERMISSIONS`.

I cannot find previous examples that refer to these variables on the developer site. Has anyone else encountered this, or do they know what these variables are supposed to refer to?

I imagine I can just declare the boolean. I am more concerned about the list.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution on another  [Stackoverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17483757/get-publish-action-permission-after-getting-read-permissions-from-facebook)

In short, these variables are simply declared. The `boolean` is initialized to `false`, and `PERMISSIONS` is initialized with a `String`

```
private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
private boolean pendingPublishReauthorization = false;
```

I was also missing the private method `isSubsetOf`

```
private boolean isSubsetOf(Collection<String> subset, Collection<String> superset) {
  for (String string : subset) {
    if (!superset.contains(string)) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```