# Facebook SDK : Android, what is the class of Request

Tags: java, android, eclipse, facebook-sdk-3.0

I have took this code from internet, to post a message on facebook, from the android app :

this is the link : [How can l post on facebook from android app with API wall without checking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17426741/how-can-l-post-on-facebook-from-android-app-with-api-wall-without-checking)

```
Request.Callback callback= new Request.Callback() {

  //some code
}
```

The problem is I don't know which Class should I import between :

_ **DownloadManager**

_ **CORBA**

_ **sun.misc**

Could you help me ? thanks you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the classes you should import for just posting to facebook wall should be:

```
//the first two what you are looking for.
import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Request.Callback;

//the rest are important to complete the posting task
import com.facebook.RequestAsyncTask;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
```

none of you have mentioned are Facebook class! did you add Facebook sdk to your project?

**Update**

here is a function I use everytime I want to post to user's timeline:

```
public static void postFB(final Context context, String message) {

    final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");

    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    if(session != null) {

        List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
        if(session.isOpened() && isSubset(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {

            Request request = Request.newStatusUpdateRequest(session, message, new Callback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                    if(error != null)
                        //show toast of the error
                    else
                        //show toast that it is posted
                }
            });

            RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
            task.execute();

        }

    }

}
```

isSubset function is used to check whether you have the permission to post or not:

```
public static boolean isSubset(Collection<String> subset, Collection<String> superset) {
    for (String string : subset) {
        if(!superset.contains(string))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

just call this the Post method passing it the context and message...
you have to put in mind that you have already added the `publish permission` when the user logged in...

as @gain1200 said, it is better to check the facebook documents here is a [good example](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious) of how to set it up

Comment: yes I did, also If you could give me a good tutorial link (maybe in private) to post a message from the app to facebook

Comment: @LeSam SO is not about "private messages". Have you checked the official doc from Facebook Developers?

Comment: did you do the Login part?

Comment: @gian1200 I was just stuck on this issue, that's why I asked another tutorial, I did a mistake in the reference setting

Comment: remove "public", "static" for PERMISSIONS

Comment: true, it suppose to be out of the function scope, thanks for fixing it

Comment: I got an error "cannot be resolved" for 'Alerts' and 'FBPosted', what should I do ?

Comment: Alerts was a class I used to show a toasts and dialogs.. check my code again I have removed it within the if/else statment

Answer (score 1):

Neither of those!!

The class Request that you're referring to is a class provided by the Facebook SDK for Android. Check out [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/class/Request/) reference page.

If you download the SDK and look at the source you'll find the definition for Request.java within com.facebook.*

so import com.facebook.*

Comment: I did a mistake in the buildpath, it's solved now, thanks you

Comment: Facebook SDK should ideally have a jar file with a packaged version of their library. Have you used the jar file or are you dumping the entire SDK source code into your project?